# How do i dynamically export variable angular

Tags: angular, dynamic, export

I am trying to export x into the HTML in a way where I can increase it by one every half second. But it looks like it's only exporting on build. I already tried injection and `ngOnChanges`, `ngDoCheck` but it's very possible that I did something wrong I am only programming with angular for about a week.

**landing.component.ts**

```js
    import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    
    var printTime = window.setInterval(increaseX, 500);
    var x = 0;
    
    function increaseX() {
      x++;
    }
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-landing',
      templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./landing.component.css']
    })
    
    export class LandingComponent{
      x = x;
    }
```

**landing.component.html**

```html
    <div class="landingText">
        <p>I Love<br>&lt;{{x}}/&gt;</p>
    </div>
```

[Rusulting Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBDTT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working, is because `x` is a primitive value. So when you do `x = x`, you are only assigning it once. When you change it outside of the class, this will not update the primitive field created on the class. It is anyways not recommendable to do things outside of classes like you have there.

The solution depends all on what you want. Personally I think you are better of using a service here. This will decouple any logic from the component and delegate it to the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class XService {
  x = 0;

  constructor() {
    window.setInterval(() => increaseX(), 500);
  }

  private increaseX(): void {
    this.x++;
  }
}
```

You can then access this value in your component:

```
export class LandingComponent{
  constructor(readonly xs: XService) {}
}
```

and show it in your template:

```
<div class="landingText">
  <p>I Love<br>&lt;{{xs.x}}/&gt;</p>
</div>
```

---

But, this will not work if you use `OnPush` change detection strategy, which is a recommended thing to use. You can even make it all cool and use the Observable pattern with the `async` pipe for this, which will look like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class XService {
  readonly x$ = interval(500);
}
```

and your template

```
<div class="landingText">
  <p>I Love<br>&lt;{{xs.x$ | async}}/&gt;</p>
</div>
```

This will survive the `OnPush` change detection.

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zlx2dv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fx.service.ts) for this solution

---

However, if you are just looking for a quick fix, you only have to change one thing really with your original code, and that is to make the `x` a getter on your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing',
  templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing.component.css']
})

export class LandingComponent{
  get x() { return x; }
}
```

This will then always get the updated value of x. Again though, this is not `OnPush` 'worthy'

Comment: I tried the method with async and it compiled successfully but it didn't show anything in the browser and put out this error message.                                                
core.js:formatted:18226 Uncaught Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!
  - JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider AOT mode instead.
  - Did you bootstrap using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server'?
  - Alternatively provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.

Comment: @Adrian I've updated my answer with a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zlx2dv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fx.service.ts) for the async solution. Your error seems a bit weird :)

Comment: thank you I managed to fix it. My service is called substring.service and I didn't realize that the readonly needed to be changed from xs to ss.:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use BehaviorSubject

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<p>{{this.$subject|async}}</p>'
 })
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   $subject: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);

   ngOnInit(): void {
    window.setInterval(() => this.$subject.next(this.$subject.value + 1), 500);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

This also works.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing',
  templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing.component.css']
})

export class LandingComponent implements OnInit  {
  x: number = 0;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const self = this;
    setInterval(() => ++self.x, 500);
  }  
}
```